# Javascript mandar uma conta para um elemento

Tags: javascript

Tenho 2 campos no meu site em que em um deles tenho que introduzir um número à medida que vou escrevendo e outro que tem de receber esse valor adicionando +3.

Usei a seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" name="ciclo" id="ciclo" maxlength="4" onkeypress="tenta()">
<input type="text" readonly id="lol">
```

e em javascript:

```
function tenta()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('ciclo');
    document.getElementById('lol').innerHTML = x + 3;
}
```

Alguém sabe porque não funciona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não estavas longe, faltam-te duas coisas.

Quando queres aceder ao valor de um `input`, e mesmo quando queres mudar o seu valor tens de usar a propriedade `.value`. No teu primeiro input deste ao `x` o próprio elemento, e não o seu valor. No segundo estás a tentar re-escrever o `.innerHTML` que o `input` não tem. Usa `.value` nos dois.

A outra coisa que falhou é porque o `.value` retorna uma *String*, ou seja um texto. Assim repara que `"10"` não é o mesmo que `10`. O primeiro é texto (*String*), o segundo um número (*Number*). Para converter podes usar o `parseInt(numero, radix)` ou o `parseFloat(numero)`.

Com essas mudanças [já ia funcionar](https://jsfiddle.net/tnfn7xv0/). Porém sugiro usares o `onkeyup`. O `keypress` é disparado **antes** de o input receber o novo numero, e assim (como no link em cima) ele vai calcular antes do novo numero lá estar. Muda para `keyup` para ele fazer a conta já com o valor certo.

Portanto para isso funcionar podes usar assim:

```js
function tenta() {
    var x = document.getElementById('ciclo').value;
    document.getElementById('lol').value = parseFloat(x) + 3;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ciclo" id="ciclo" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tenta()">
<input type="text" readonly id="lol">
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tnfn7xv0/1/

Answer (score 2):

É necessário usar [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) para fazer este cálculo, senão o número `3` será apenas adicionado à frente do `value` que estamos a obter da primeira `div` para fazer o seu *output* para uma segunda `div`.
Ou seja, se adicionássemos o número `2` no `input`, o seu resultado na segunda `div` que é o *output*, apareceria assim desta seguinte forma - **`23`** e não o valor correto que supostamente seria - `5`.

Neste caso podemos utilizar o [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), que basicamente o que ele faz é - "devolver o valor de um número arredondado para o número inteiro mais próximo". Assim se colocarmos valores com pontos ou vírgulas, ela automaticamente faz o arredondamento.

```js
var inputInserido = document.getElementById('userInput');
var resuldado = document.getElementById('preview');

inputInserido.onkeyup = function(){
    resuldado.innerHTML = Math.round(inputInserido.value) + 3;
}
```

```css
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="userInput" />
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: Acho que `Math.round()` não é semanticamente correto. Ele funciona porque converte a string em numero, da mesma maneira que `typeof ("5" * 1)` dá um `"number"`. Os métodos `parseInt` ou `parseFloat` é o que é semântico para converter strings em numeros.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo a função **onkeyup** que é executada depois que você solta o botão de cima do input. Na linha **var x = document.getElementById('ciclo')** você não pega o valor do input e sim o Objeto, para pegar o valor use a propriedade **value**.

```js
function tenta() {
    var x = document.getElementById('ciclo').value;
    //parseInt converte a string do input para inteiro
    document.getElementById('lol').value = parseInt(x) + 3;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ciclo" id="ciclo" maxlength="4" onkeyup="tenta()">
<input type="text" readonly id="lol">
```

Comment: muito bom Igor +1 :)

Comment: Obrigado @Chun a sua também está muito bem explicado!